# raise notice update query result in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I log if field is got updated or not using `RAISE NOTICE` or some other command if available.

```
do
$BODY$
DECLARE 
is_updated int;
BEGIN
is_updated := UPDATE my_schema.my_table  SET support_email = 'support@gmail.com' WHERE id = '9e7080d9-97d9-4d8b-90c5-c02bf5f04ecd';
IF is_updated > 0 THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'Row got updated';
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'No Row is updated';
END IF;
END
$BODY$
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could something like below, but I am not sure if there another `UPDATE` query followed by current one, `ROW_COUNT` will hold new result;

```
do
$BODY$
DECLARE 
is_updated int;
BEGIN
UPDATE my_schema.my_table  SET support_email = 'hell@gmail.com' WHERE id = 'bf2f9e57-2c98-447e-abe3-0edf2a61185e';
get diagnostics is_updated = ROW_COUNT;

if is_updated > 0 then
     raise notice 'Row got updated';
else
    raise notice 'No Row is updated';
end if;
END
$BODY$
```

Comment: The diagnostics are always from the latest DML command.

Comment: So do the `FOUND`?

Comment: `FOUND` is simpler, but your solution is just as good. My comment just tried to dispel the doubts uttered in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [special variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) `FOUND` to check if `UPDATE` command,  update rows

```
do
$BODY$
BEGIN
UPDATE my_schema.my_table  SET support_email = "hell@gmail.com" WHERE id = "9e7080d9-97d9-4d8b-90c5-c02bf5f04ecd";
IF FOUND THEN
     RAISE NOTICE 'Row got updated';
ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'No Row is updated';
END IF;
END
$BODY$
```